# How to record sound from digital keyboard to computer?

Tags: piano, computer

I'm trying to record my digital keyboard/piano (Yamaha) onto my laptop (Hp) and I've looked all over online, YouTube, downloaded various software programs, etc., and I can't find out how... thanks!!!
PS, also what are some of the best software programs (other than garageband, because it only works on mac) to use to do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this an electric piano that you want to record via the cable, or a piano that you want to mic up?

Comment: its an electric piano, yes, I want to record via cable

Comment: what model is it?

Comment: it says it's a Yamaha portatone electronic keyboard

Comment: There are lots of 'portatone' keyboards. The exact model number would help.

Answer (score 2):

Recording a keyboard needs the following things - an audio interface, a pair of high quality headphones, a computer and a keyboard.

There are different audio interfaces available to choose from. To give you a list of the same would include the following:

- [Presonus AudioBox USB {2X2 Interface}](https://www.presonus.com/products/AudioBox-USB)
- [Roland Duo Capture {2x2 Interface}](https://www.roland.com/us/products/duo-capture/)
- [Focusrite Scarlett 2i2 {2x2 Interface}](https://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-2i2)

Once you have a suitable audio interface, you can connect the keyboard from its audio output jack to the audio interface's input and then connect the USB out from the interface into a USB jack of your laptop. To **monitor** the sound, you must connect the headphones to the interface (and wear them).

Talking about softwares, there are loads and loads of free ones that will work in your case with ease. Here's list of some:

- [Audacity {Free & most easy to use}](http://www.audacityteam.org/)
- [Presonus Studio One {Recommended to use with the Presonus AudioBox USB Interface}](http://www.presonus.com/products/Studio-One)
- [Adobe Audition {NOT FREE but also a very easy to use and preferred software}](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/audition.html)
- [Cubase LE {Paid pro software}](http://www.steinberg.net/en/landing_pages/cubase_le_7/download_cubase_le_7.html)

If you don't wish to go through this way, then there's another easy and free way to record your keyboard. Connect the keyboard via USB directly as a midi keyboard. Then you have to download [VST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology) plugins from [VST4Free.com](http://vst4free.com) and using a software like [Cocos Reaper](http://reaper.fm) or [Nuendo](http://www.steinberg.net/en/support/downloads/downloads_nuendo_6.html), you can record tracks of your performance. However, the sound will not be that of your keyboard but that of the VST plugins you download. This method is not very fruitful unless you have professional VSTs (which need money). To record your own keyboard, buy an interface and make your studio setup.

This is to sum up how to record a keyboard on your laptop. You will have to go through several tutorials and failed audio production attempts before you can successfully get the best recording of your performance. Good luck with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that keyboard has midi out so you could buy a cheap midi to USB adapter and free midi software like http://midieditor.sourceforge.net/.